# Параллельное существование и выполнение

Tags: c++, qt

Столкнулся с ситуацией, насколько понимаю мне необходимо, чтобы некоторая часть программы работала независимо от другой, но как точно описать данный процесс в среде программирования пока мне не дано понять.

Пример таков: в локальной сети передаются данные, мне необходимо чтобы одна часть программы (модуль) их перехватывала.
Далее встает вопрос обработки этих данных по некоторому алгоритму, необходимо ли описывать другой модуль, чтобы обрабатывать эта данные или же все это лучше исполнять в первой части. И завершающим этапом обработанная информация должна быть передана в третью часть, этот модуль самостоятельно, через определенные интервалы времени, будет пересылать данные в адрес.

Прошу помочь советом, каким образом это все лучше организовать и с помощью каких методов (инструментов).

Comment: Язык с++? Я вижу так: первый модуль качает данные, обрабатывает и сохраняет в базу данных. Второй модуль через определенные промежутки времени лезет в ту базу и пересылает их куда-то. Базу данных можно использовать sqlite. А модули реализовать или через потоки/процессы. Или как отдельные самостоятельные программы

Comment: Все в режиме реалтайм и с большими объемами. Задачи хранить в базе нет. Основная задача, максимально эффективно собрать информацию, обработать и передать.

Comment: Раз используете qt, то думаю правильнее было бы использовать сигналы или события для общения модулей. Тобишь когда модуль перехватывает данные, он высылает сигнал обработчику либо с данными, либо, если вы их записали куда-то, просто сигнал о готовности. И так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью инструментов Qt. А именно использовал QThread для параллельного выполнения разных объектов, а так же QTime, QTimer для выполнения определенного кода через определенные промежутки времени.